# How to create stretchy image in static cell tableview when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

How to create a stretchy self adjusting image in a static cell tableview as seen in this tutorial? http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/

But for static cells instead of dynamic cells.

edit:

```
class ProfileViewController2: UITableViewController {

    var profilePic = "WilsonLer"
    private let kTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 189
    var headerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var topHeader: UITableViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        self.navigationItem.title = user!.email

        headerView = topHeader
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kTableHeaderHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight)
        updateHeaderView()



        // to set and display profile image
        let profilePicImage = topHeader.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let profilePicBG = topHeader.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        profilePicImage.image = UIImage(named: profilePic)
        profilePicBG.image = UIImage(named: profilePic)
        profilePicImage.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicImage.frame.height/2
        profilePicImage.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePicImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        profilePicImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateHeaderView() {

        var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)
        if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight {

            headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
            headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y

        }
        topHeader.frame = headerRect

    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateHeaderView()
    }



}
```

I've tried the method in the link but still to no avail. Tried creating a subclass for the cell too but it will only work for dynamic cells.

this was all I got with a non scrolling header:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way. The image is a header. It has nothing to do with the cells being dynamic or static. If you want to test it, simply add 1 blank static cell, a `UIImage` header & add the code for the header. It should work fine.

Note: With static cells you will have to create a custom class for each cell.

Note 2: Next time you ask a question like this at least put some effort in trying yourself. Don't expect to ask a question & people to do YOUR work.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a custom *class* for each cell, but the rest of this checks out.